# Running multiple iOS simulators with React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to run the app in multiple IOS simulators with React Native so will be able to compare the iPhone version vs the iPad version

I see there is some one already did it
https://ashleyd.ws/running-multiple-ios-simulators-with-react-native/

but unfortunate he did not mention how he did it

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Using MacOs Terminal, launch first simulator:

1. `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications`
2. `open -n Simulator.app`
3. `cd <your react native project>`
4. `react-native run-ios`

Now, launch 2nd simulator:

5. `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications`
6. `open -n Simulator.app`
7. Click "Ok" when you get "Unable to boot device in current state"
8. Change simulator to be different than first simulator (e.g. Hardware -> Device -> iPhone 6s)
9. `cd <react-native project>`
10. `react-native run-ios --simulator "iPhone 6s"` (or whatever simulator you chose in step 8).

Note: In the last step, you can disregard the terminal output since it indicates that it is launching using the 1st simulator hardware.  In fact, it is launching into the 2nd simulator (as desired).

Comment: I followed your steps , in step 10 it will install the app in the first simulator
also tried to used --simulator , didn't work too

I have Pod file .xcworkspace . Do you think this is the reason ?
<code>
react-native run-ios "iPhone 5s"
Found Xcode workspace test.xcworkspace
Launching iPhone 6 (9.3)...
</code>

Comment: I'm not sure -- I haven't had to use workspaces so far for with my React app.  Could you download an example React Native application that uses Xcode project to confirm that you are able to get two simulators using the above method?

Comment: It works for me for running same app on different simulators. Does anyone know how to run different react native apps on different simulators? like app A on one and App B on another?

Comment: You need to ensure different apps use different port for its react packager.  

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  NSString *str = [jsCodeLocation absoluteString];
  NSString *newJsLoc = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"8081" withString:@"8082"];
  jsCodeLocation = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:newJsLoc];

Comment: anyway to programmatically tell open -n Simulator.app to pick an OS beforehand? Would make this entire process scriptable

Comment: it works for me but how can I get "hot reloading" to work on both? only hot reloads on once instance of simulator currently for me.

Comment: Seems to not work anoymore with XCode 8.3.2 as it is stating "Unable to boot device in current state: Booted" from up to the second launched simulator

Comment: This approach works, however, now when I re-launch a single run-ios command, I get multiple bundles loaded and two debuggers are launched. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't work in Xcode 11. They don't let you run multiple sims that way anymore. You do it from the Devices menu. But I tried starting another sim with that then running with the `--simulator` option, didn't work.

Answer (score 13):

I got two separate react native apps running at the same time doing this

I entered the following in one terminal for the first app

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone X"
```

After that finished building I opened another terminal and ran for the second app

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone XS" --port=8088
```

Then that built the second app on the new simulator and using a different port for the metro bundler. However after the second one built the first app changed its screen from the first app to the second app. I hit the home button and just re-opened the first app. One observation is that the first app seems to have both apps installed in the simulator while the second one does not.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the direct answer to your question, but I think it gives a better solution than running different simulators.
You can check the following lib called [ScreenSwitcher](https://github.com/calvium/react-native-device-screen-switcher).

It basically use the same simulator, in our case `iPhone 6 plus` only and you can check and inspect any other smaller screen on it directly.
I find that approach more efficient and faster.

[image: ScreenSwitcher]

Comment: This would work if all you want is to run your UI on various screen sizes. When the goal is to debug the interaction of multiple devices this is not a solution.

Comment: Yes, your correct. If you need to run multiple simulators at once, you need to open up multiple debuggers on different ports at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Opening multiple simulators from the command-line did not work for me. With some manual interaction I got this to work with simulator 10.0 and react-native 0.47.2 - its based on the fact that react native always opens the app in the last opened simulator:

- manually open simulator
- start app: react-native run-ios
- manually do: Hardware -> Device -> select iOS -> select Device (different then before !)
- that will open a second simulator
- start app again: react-native run-ios
- this opens the app in the second simulator

Comment: React native 0.55.2 here. I don't have the `react-native` command, but the equivalent `npm run ios` fails when multiple sims are open. Also using Xcode 11, btw.

Answer (score 1):

```
I have Used more than 2 Simulator at a one time by using different terminals and they works well 

react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 11 Pro Max"  //write like this.
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6".          //write like this.
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 12 Pro Max"  //write like this.
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8 Plus".
```

Comment: Legend! worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to run the app from xcode plus open another one from react-native commandline. Each normally opens their own simulator (I wonder why). And if I run an end-to-end test with Detox then it also opens its own simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers above helped me, but I think they are incomplete.

I have been using this technique to test a two player game (halfchess.com) on iOS simulators. My goal is to run two instances of halfchess at the same time.

To have my app running on two simulators, I first need to `install Expo app on multiple simulators`. Below steps are for the first time only.

1. `react-native-scripts start` to run the package manager. Copy the
   expo URL for the app, for ex., exp://172.20.10.2:19000 to clipboard.
2. Run ios simulator from within above (press `i`). This opens a default simulator and runs the app. Lets call the default device `X`.
3. Goto menu `Hardware -> Device -> iOS -> select a different device`
4. Close the current device from `File -> Close Window`. Now we have only one window open.
5. Install expo app on this device by restarting package manger and pressing `i` again for install.
6. Now we can open the earlier closed device `X` again. Open simulator and open the expo app.
7. The expo URL from step 1 should be in clipboard textarea for the expo app. Launch the app by clicking the URL.

For next time onwards, the picked devices already have an expo app installed.

1. Do step 1 as above.
2. Open the default `X` and the other device `Y`.
3. Open e

xpo apps on devices and follow step 7 to run the app on both simulators.

So its much faster the second time onwards.

**The downside with this is that logs from both simulators appear in the same terminal. Right now, I have cloned the project in a different directory, and do `react-native-scrips start` from a different terminal; and use the second expo URL generated in one of the simulators.** The logs from both simulators now appear in different terminals. There should be better ways to do this.

PS - I am currently on version 10+ of xcode.